# Bash - Check if the standard input contains anything

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I know this question has been asked several times but it seems ineffective in my case.

`[[ ! -t 0 ]]` = Does standard input contains anything?

This command:

```
echo 'Hello world' | [[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives the correct output: `0`, i.e. the standard input contains anything.
This command:

```
[[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives the correct output: `1`, i.e. the standard input is empty.
Instead this command:

```
: | [[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives unexpected output: `0`, when instead the standard input is empty: `1`.

Why does it behave this way and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: The operator `-t` doesn't check if there is input; it checks whether the file handle is connected to a `tty` (i.e. generally a terminal). If there is a terminal, input could arrive at any time, so in some sense it's the opposite of what you seem to want.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I made a mistake, I misunderstood the meaning.

Comment: See [How to check if a pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33049/264812).  Note the comments saying that `read -t0` is broken in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it behave this way

`-t` checks if file descriptor is connected to a TTY.

> how can I solve the problem?

Read 1 byte. If you did read it, it's not empty, otherwise it's empty.

```
... | {
   if IFS= read -d '' -n 1; then
       echo 'Not empty!' >&2
       # forward data along if you want to
       if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; then
           printf "%s" "$REPLY"
       else
           # properly handle zero byte in input
           printf "\x00"
       fi
       cat
   else
       echo 'empty!' >&2
   fi
} | ...
```

Note that, because it is not possible to hold a zero byte in Bash, the above code check the `[[ -n "$REPLY" ]]` to handle zero byte. You could also do something with `dd` and `xxd` or some custom program would to handle it zero bytes.

Comment: Where did you get the "$REPLY" variable from?

Comment: `REPLY` is set by `read`. See `read --help`.

Comment: There is a trick to enable `read` to handle zero/NUL bytes in input.  See [BashFAQ/058 (Can bash handle binary data?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/058).  It contains code to "simulate cat with just bash builtins, binary safe".

Comment: Sure, so you could do `if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; then printf "%s" "$REPLY"; else printf "\x00"; fi`. I usually don't care about zero bytes / assume they won't be there when checking if empty. Added, nice! I wonder, would `printf "${REPLY:+%s}${REPLY:-\x00}" "$REPLY"` be better?

Comment: I think you need to use `IFS= read -d '' -n 1` to handle input that starts with whitespace (including newline) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing:

- `[ -t 0 ]` or `test -t 0`, which tests if file descriptor 0 (stdin) is connected to a terminal, as others have already explained
- with `read -t 0`, which tests if there is something to read on stdin (or on the file descriptor specified with the `-u` option), without actually reading it

### Tests

(read also the caveat section below)

```bash
$ echo 'Hello world' | read -t 0
$ echo $?
0
```

```bash
$ read -t 0
$ echo $?
1
```

```bash
$ : | read -t 0
$ echo $?
1
```

### Relevant part of the manual

> `read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]`
>
> Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
>
> (...)
>
> `-t timeout`
>
> Time out and return failure if a complete line of input is
> not read within TIMEOUT seconds. The value of the TMOUT
> variable is the default timeout. TIMEOUT may be a fractional number.
> **If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately, without
> trying to read any data, returning success only if input is
> available on the specified file descriptor.**
> The exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded

### Caveat

There is an inherent race condition with a construct such as `echo something | read -t 0` because, by default, each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process and you have no control over which process is started first. Moreover, even if `echo` is started first, it may be interrupted before it has written anything to stdout.

So, sometimes, `read -t0` will return 0 as you may expect, but sometimes `read` will be executed before anything is written to the pipe and will return 1.

As suggested by @F.Hauri in comment, you may want to add some delay before testing whether there is something to read, but there is no guarantee this will work every time. Anyway, if you use a non-blocking read, then I assume you expect to retry your read later.

Comment: Yes, `-t` switch of `read` command is for *`timeout`*, but with 0 as *timeout*, `read` return immediately without reading anything, but return 0 (true)  if data are ready to read and return 1 (false) if no data are present.

Comment: But use pseudo variable `_` as *variable name* for `read` command: `read -t 0 _` as `read`command require a variable name or use `$REPLY` by default. Using `$_` prevent this test command to modify anything in current environment.

Comment: Use sample: `echo 'Hello world!'  | if read -t 0 _ ; then read line; echo "$line"; fi`

Comment: For me, `echo Hello world | read -t 0` always exits with 1. `echo 'Hello world' | read -t 0.0001` exits sometimes with 142 and sometimes with 0.

Comment: @KamilCuk You'r  right, I noticed this just now! A kind or race condition, I repeated this again and again and sometime...

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added the relevant part of the `read` help to my answer

Comment: @KamilCuk Try this: `{ sleep .001; if read -t 0 _ ;then read line;echo "$line";fi } < <(echo 'Hello world!')` or this `echo Hello world | { sleep .0001; read -t 0 _;echo $?;}`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Yes, there is an inherent race condition due to the way Bash spawns its two child processes. This is something I already covered in the past on SO or U.SE, I'll try to find my answer.

Comment: @xhienne hmm correct, but as bash is currently running his *own* process, they have to spawn only 1 *other* process... (so you'd better written: *...the way bash spawn it's second process...* just sementic ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub « bash is currently running his own process, they have to spawn only 1 other process » Not by default, only with `shopt -s lastpipe`

Comment: @xhienne Unfortunately I also get the `echo 'Hello world' | read -t 0; echo $?` always returns `1`. Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo read previious commnents and try: `echo Hello world | { sleep .0001; read -t 0 _;echo $?;}`

Comment: @MarioPalumbo I have added a caveat section to my answer

Comment: sleep 0 also works but not other commands, why?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo Anything that adds some delay and that may force the kernel to run the other process (read) will work most of the time. But it may not work under heavy load. That's what I wrote in my caveat: there is no absolute guarantee. Of course, if you `sleep 1h`, that will work 99.99999999% of the time, but that defeats the purpose of a non-lbocking read IMHO

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I had guessed it.

Comment: (too many comments to cope with :-) @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub « `read` command require a variable name or use `$REPLY` » `read -t0` does not read anything and thus does not change the value of `REPLY`. Moreover I consider `$_` as a reserved variable and I would not use it either, as it may cause confusion to the inadvertent reader of my code

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added a caveat section to address `echo | read -t 0` returning sometimes 0 and sometimes 1. As to why `read -t 0.001` returns 142, this is covered by the manual I quoted in my answer: `read` was interrupted by a `SIGALRM` signal before the read was successful

Comment: Unfortunately also `: | { sleep .0001; read -t 0 _;echo $?;}` returns 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256139/discussion-between-xhienne-and-mario-palumbo).

Comment: This situation is more difficult than it appears.
ifne in moreutils package is not flexible and forces me to do an if then, instead I need it to give me a simple exit code so I can do an if then else.
The fact that this triviality is not easy to solve is worth mentioning as a feature request for bash as well as the "pipe if success" symbolism `&|`.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, ..."pipe if success" doesn't make sense. If it doesn't start both sides in parallel (meaning before success/failure of the left is known), it's not a shell pipe. `ifne` at least can get out of the way after a single byte is written; "pipe if success" (assuming that it checks the left-hand side's exit status) would need to buffer all the way to end of execution.